# Implementing tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath: will cause strange scroll behavior. How to fix it

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In my `UITableView` I implemented the `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` method to speed up loading it. I also have an `NSFetchedResultsController` to display it's content.

When a new entry affecting my `UITableView` is made, having implemented `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` will cause the scroll position in the tableview to be somewhere wrong.

Here you can see it in action using just Apples Template for a Master-Detail View App any dynamic cell heights:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/809469/UITableView-Problem-With-EstimatedContentHeights.zip
Everything I changed was to add a randomHeight Property to the CoreData Entity and use that one for height information.

You can see the effect if you add several entries and then scroll to the bottom of the `UITableView` and insert a new object. Then it will scroll to a wrong position...

Commenting out `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` would fix it...

I could now to fix it myself remember the contentOffset in `controllerWillChangeContent:`, apply changes to it for inserts/deleted/updates and then apply the fixed contentOffset it again in `controllerDidChangeContent:`, but my question is if I am simply doing something wrong?!?

Comment: Your problem tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath: not in 
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController method I build your code it works fine with estimateHeight but I set the heightFor 60.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... what do you mean? I know that the code works, but scrolling down and then adding a new entry (+ button) will cause the scroll position to be messed up

Comment: you have problem in calculating the height of the row..

Comment: Why? Everything is fine with `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`?!? Implementing `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` kind of breaks it. What do you think I am doing wrong?

As I understood the `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` method I am giving back a height that kind of fits... Not something that is really correct?!? Isn't that the whole point of this method?